# Why does data packing 4 integers into a 32 bit integer have different results in Nextion and Teensy(Arduino compatible)

Tags: packing, nextion

I'm controlling a Teensy 3.5 with a Nextion touchscreen. On the Nextion the following code packs 4 8 bit integers into a 32 bit integer:
`sys0=vaShift_24.val<<8|vaShift_16.val<<8|vaShift_8.val<<8|vaShift_0.val`
Using the same shift amount (8) has a different result on the Teensy, however, the following generates the same result:
`combinedValue = (v24 << 24) | (v16 << 16) | (v08 << 8) | (v00);`
I'm curious why these shifts work differently.
Nextion documentation: https://nextion.tech/instruction-set/

```
//Nextion:
vaShift_24.val=5
vaShift_16.val=4
vaShift_8.val=1
vaShift_0.val=51
sys0=vaShift_24.val<<8|vaShift_16.val<<8|vaShift_8.val<<8|vaShift_0.val

//Result is 84148531

//Teensy, Arduino, C++:

    value24 = 5;
    value16 = 4;
    value8 = 1;
    value0 = 51;
    packedValue = (value24 << 24) | (value16 << 16) | (value8 << 8) | (value0);
    Serial.print("24 to 0: ");
    Serial.println(packedValue);
    packedValue = (value24 << 8) | (value16 << 8) | (value8 << 8) | (value0);
    Serial.print("8: ");
    Serial.println(packedValue);

    //Result:
    //24 to 0: 84148531
 //8: 1331
```

Comment: *"Using the same shift amount (8) has a different result on the Teensy,"* how do you know this? My guess is, you are looking at some kind of hex dump. Please show the dump (or, if you can't copy-paste it, screenshot from a debugger or something is better than nothing).

Comment: Please edit the question with any new info you add (and no meed to mark it as "edit", just edit).

Comment: Nextion:
`
vaShift_24.val=5
vaShift_16.val=4
vaShift_8.val=1
vaShift_0.val=51
sys0=vaShift_24.val<<8|vaShift_16.val<<8|vaShift_8.val<<8|vaShift_0.val
`
Result is 84148531

Teensy, Arduino, C++:
`
 value24 = 5;
 value16 = 4;
 value8 = 1;
 value0 = 51;
 packedValue = (value24 << 24) | (value16 << 16) | (value8 << 8) | (value0);
 Serial.print("24 to 0: ");
 Serial.println(packedValue);
 packedValue = (value24 << 8) | (value16 << 8) | (value8 << 8) | (value0);
 Serial.print("8: ");
 Serial.println(packedValue);
`
 Result:
 24 to 0: 84148531
8: 1331

Comment: There is an "edit" link below the _question_...

Comment: Is everyone stumped???

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be in this line:

```
sys0=vaShift_24.val<<8|vaShift_16.val<<8|vaShift_8.val<<8|vaShift_0.val
```

You are shifting by 8 in many places. Presumably you want:

```
sys0 = vaShift_24.val << 24  | vaShift_16.val << 16 | vaShift_8.val << 8 | vaShift_0.val
```

---

Now result from bytes 5, 4, 1, and 55 should be, in hex
`0x05040133`.
If you are instead seeing
`0x33010405`
it means you would also have a byte order issue. But probably not.